# Adding OR in IF function in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to but an OR in this IF statement. For example IF `cell="2"` OR IF `cell="4"` OR IF `cell="hello"`. 
Can you help me? In the current code i have only an IF `cell="2"`.

```
Cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(left(RC[2],1)=""2"",""delete"",""1"")"
```

Comment: You could have googled this , the format is 
=IF(OR(a=1,b=2,c=3),TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: [OR](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/OR-function-7D17AD14-8700-4281-B308-00B131E22AF0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested but hopefully will work):

```
Cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(left(RC[2],1)=""2"",left(RC[2],1)=""4"",left(RC[2],1)=""hello""),""delete"",""1"")"
```